# Meaning of がい in だろうがい

Tags: grammar, particles

What exactly does "がい" mean in the phrase "リーダーは俺だろうがい"?

To give some context, here's part of the video I heard it from:
https://youtu.be/44UruxeJ_20?t=1127

This was said by a comedian, so maybe it's an exaggerated and uncommon way of speaking.

Or maybe it's just "tough guy speech."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

「～～だろうが」 is an accusatory sentence-ender used primarily by male speakers.  The 「が」 is a particle.

「がい」, though not too common, is an emphatic and tougher-sounding version of that 「が」.

Likewise, for emphasis, 「か」 for questioning becomes 「かい」 and 「だ」 for affirmation or declaration becomes 「だい」.

Though 「かい」 and 「だい」 are far more common than 「がい」, I do not think 「がい」 is dialectal.  (The speaker in the video grew up in Kanagawa, which is right next to Tokyo.)